# VB.Net 2010 - Retrieve MemberValue from ComboBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding

I have been working on this for three days now and just can’t find a simple answer. (It really can’t be that hard to do surly). but now I can’t see the trees for the forest anymore.

I populate a Combobox from an SQL database, this works fine and the data shows up fine in the Dataset Visualizer.

ComboList is called cmbStateList

Two Database fields 
DisplayMember “State”
ValueMember “ID”

What I want to do is simply return the ValueMember of when an item is selected from the combobox.
When I use “cmbStateList.SelectedValue” in the cmbStateList_SelectedIndexChanged what is returned is the index or position of the item in the list, not the ValueMember (“ID”) field of the data.

Here is the code I am using, really hope someone can help with this simple problem

### Load the State List:

```
SQL = "Select * from State"
Command = New SqlCommand(SQL, CNN)
DA.SelectCommand = Command
DA.Fill(DS, "State")
```

### Bind the ComboBox:

```
Me.cmbStateList.Items.Clear()
Me.cmbStateList.DataSource = DS.Tables("State")
Me.cmbStateList.DisplayMember = "State"
Me.cmbStateList.ValueMember = "ID"
```

### Select the ComboBox (Have tried DropDownClosed and SelectedIndexChanged):

```
Private Sub cmbStateList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbStateList.SelectedIndexChanged
     MsgBox(Me.cmbStateList.SelectedValue)
End Sub
```

Thanking you in advance
Chris

Answer (score 1):

This is very slowly if you have arround 100000 records:

```
Me.cmbStateList.DataSource = Nothing
Me.cmbStateList.DataSource = DS.Tables("State")
Me.cmbStateList.DisplayMember = "State"
Me.cmbStateList.ValueMember = "ID"
```

This is fast, just changed the orders of commands:

```
Me.cmbStateList.DataSource = Nothing
Me.cmbStateList.DisplayMember = "State"
Me.cmbStateList.ValueMember = "ID"
Me.cmbStateList.DataSource = DS.Tables("State")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if it will make a difference, but we always set our Members before the DataSource. I would try changing your code to the following:

```
Me.cmbStateList.DataSource = Nothing
Me.cmbStateList.DisplayMember = "State"
Me.cmbStateList.ValueMember = "ID"
Me.cmbStateList.DataSource = DS.Tables("State")
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I think you might have meant move the binding datasource to the end. I did this and then I get System.Data.DataRowView loaded in the combobox, no data. I realy cant belive it can be this hard to simply display the value..

Comment: You are welcome, and welcome to stackoverflow! Remember, if an answer solves or helps you solve your question, you should click the checkmark and up arrow next to the question so that future visitors know this is what helped you with your question.

Comment: Just did somthing Diffrent...

It seems to works if you use a DataTable
Does that mean you cant use a DataSource to bind to a combobox?

Comment: Does not work if the Combobox is Sorted.. this seems to be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Bind the combo box

```
Me.cmbStateList.Items.Clear()
Me.cmbStateList.DisplayMember = "State"
Me.cmbStateList.ValueMember = "ID"
Me.cmbStateList.DataSource = DS.Tables("State")
Me.cmbStateList.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Get selected value

To test add this on a button click event handeler.

```
MsgBox(Me.cmbStateList.SelectedValue.ToString())
```

Comment: 1 QLD
2 NSW
3 WA
4 SA
5 ACT
6 VIC
NULL NULL

Comment: It seems really strange because what is displayed is the position of the record in the combobox. 
So if it is the 2nd item from the top it shows 2, 3rd item is 3 the first item is 1 (not zero as I would expect). 

Below is the data from the database showing the states and ID number.  
1         QLD
2 NSW
3 WA
4 SA
5 ACT
6 VIC 

So it is pretty simple stuff.

Do you think that SelectedIndexChanged is the right area to check?
Honest been playing with this for three days straight, driving me mad.

Thanks for you time on helping

Comment: I am new to this forum, and it seems if you press the enter key to enter a new line it posts your comments.

I have learned to hold down the Shift key and press enter to start a new line.

Comment: Found the answer thanks to someone on VBWire.
Great forum and lots of answers.

The answer is for anyone who has the same problem you must sort the DataSet before you bind it to the Combobox.

DS being the Dataset

Dim Table As DataTable = DS.Tables("State")
Table.DefaultView.Sort = "State"

I would say .net (2010 anyway) is a major regression in fast and easy coding. Everything is so long winded and so un-intuitive... The days of quick and cost effective coding may be on it's last legs.

Thanks a lot to BizApps as being the only person to answer and I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: or you can add order by State on your select query